# Isn't this Interest-ing?

Tags: c++, beginner, homework, finance

This is the fifth project in my CS1 class.  It's a bit more drab than my past projects, so my titles are getting worse unfortunately. `:(`

> Write a program that computes the annual after-tax cost of a new house
>   for the first year of ownership.  The cost is computed as the annual
>   mortgage cost minus the tax savings.  The input should be the price of
>   the house and the down payment.  The annual mortgage cost can be
>   estimated as \$ 3\% \$ of the initial loan balance credited toward
>   paying of the loan principal plus \$ 6\% \$ of the initial loan
>   balance in interest.  The initial loan balance is the price minus the
>   down payment.  Assume a \$ 35\% \$ marginal tax rate and assume that
>   interest payments are tax deductible.  So, the tax savings is \$ 35\% \$
>   of the interest payment.  Your program should use at least two
>   function definitions and should allow the user to repeat this
>   calculation as often as the user wishes.

I may have cheated a bit with my required two function definitions...

**`mortgage.cpp`**:

```
/**
 * @file mortgage.cpp
 * @brief Computes the annual after-tax cost of a new house
 * @author syb0rg
 * @date 10/9/14
 */

#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

/**
 * Makes sure data isn't malicious, and signals user to re-enter proper data if invalid
 */
long double getSanitizedDouble()
{
    long double input = 0.0L;
    while(!(std::cin >> input) || input < 0)
    {
        // clear the error flag that was set so that future I/O operations will work correctly
        std::cin.clear();
        // skips to the next newline
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        std::cout << "Invalid input.  Please enter a positive number: ";
    }
    return input;
}

/**
 * Safetly grabs and returns a lowercase version of the character (if the lowercase exists)
 */
char32_t getSanitizedChar()
{
    // absorb newline character (if existant) from previous input
    if(std::cin.peek() == '\n') std::cin.ignore();
    return std::tolower(std::cin.get());
}

int main()
{
    do
    {
        long double housePrice = 0.0L;
        long double downPayment = 0.0L;

        // get input for house price, re-read input if not a positive number
        std::cout << "Enter the price of the house: $";
        housePrice = getSanitizedDouble();

        // get input for down payment, re-read input if not a positive number
        std::cout << "Enter the down-payment: $";
        downPayment = getSanitizedDouble();

        long double loanBalance = housePrice - downPayment;
        long double interest = .06 * loanBalance;
        long double annualMortgage = (.03 * loanBalance) + interest;
        long double savings = .35 * interest;
        long double totalCost = annualMortgage - savings;

        std::cout << "The annual after-tax cost of the house is $" << totalCost << std::endl;

        std::cout << "Run the program again (y/N): ";  // signify n as default with capital letter
    } while ('y' == getSanitizedChar());
}
```

Comment: I understand that this is homework, but I must still caution all readers about using floating point numbers when dealing with money. It's a big no-no. Round off errors will very quickly accumulate and money will get lost. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency

Comment: @EmilyL. Very [Office Space-like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salami_slicing)

Comment: @sjagr Of course, the guys in Office Space took [Superman III](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman_III) as _their_ inspiration :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Some minor changes I would recommend:

- Replace the magic numbers with symbolic constants. It will be easier to
  modify your program when these rates change.

  ```
  constexpr long double ANNUAL_MORTGAGE_COST = 0.03; 
  constexpr long double LOAN_PRINCIPAL_PLUS = 0.06;
  constexpr long double MARGINAL_TAX_RATE = 0.35;
  ```
- Instead of doing the calculations inside `main()` I would suggest
  putting it into a function.

  ```
  long double totalPayment(long double housePrice, long double downPayment){

      long double loanBalance = housePrice - downPayment;
      long double interest = LOAN_PRINCIPAL_PLUS * loanBalance;
      long double annualMortgage = (ANNUAL_MORTGAGE_COST * loanBalance) + interest;
      long double savings = MARGINAL_TAX_RATE * interest;
      long double totalCost = annualMortgage - savings;

      return totalCost;
  }
  ```

Comment: Perhaps, const references instead? Just for efficiency and safety.

Comment: @Dave It is generally considered that built-in types are fast enough to be passed by value.

Comment: You switched ANNUAL_MORTGAGE_COST and LOAN_PRINCIPAL_PLUS in the interest and annualMortgage calculations.  This might have been more obvious if you'd named them PRINCIPAL_REDUCTION_RATE and INTEREST_RATE instead.

Comment: @Brythan Good catch.

Answer (score 13):

A few minor things to complete what has already been said. Almost none of them are significant, but good practice is good practice.

- You don't need to use `std::endl`: it prints a newline character *and* flushes the buffer, which is unneeded here. You can simply use `\n`. It won't make a difference in your program, but it is still good practice.

  *Note: as pointed out by @Emily, it flushes the buffer [for buffered input only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25569849/1364752), which isn't the case of `std::cout`, unless manually redirected to a file. I'll keep this comment here anyway, not because I still believe that it is good practice, but because knowing about it might still be useful.*
- `housePrice` and `downPayment` could be declared later and directly initialized with `getSanitizedDouble`. There is no point in declaring them at the beginning of your `do {} while ()` block.
- `getSanitizedChar` returns `char32_t`. While this is fine, it may make more sense to return an `int` (return type of `std::tolower`) or a `char` since you read from `std::cin` which is an instance of `std::basic_istream<char>`.
- You used the wrong literal in `while(!(std::cin >> input) || input < 0)`, it should be `0.0L` (haha, found one :p).
- Also, some say it is a matter of style, many don't like it, but it is good practice to put braces around single-statement `if`s. Had every Apple developer done this, the infamous [`goto fail;` bug](http://www.cigital.com/justice-league-blog/2014/02/25/understanding-apple-goto-fail-vulnerability-2/) wouldn't have been a thing.

Comment: Using `\n` over `std::endl` is a matter of style and I would prefer using the latter. Under some circumstances using `\n` can avoid a costly buffer flush but I consider consistently using `\n` a premature optimisation. More information: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25569849/2498188

Comment: +1 for "some say it is a matter of style" - I've been coding `if(condition)doif();else doelse();` for years, and only recently (on own accord) switched to `if(condition){doif();}else {doelse();}` - and I'm happy with it, mainly because I don't type those braces - I use IDE autoformatting/autocompletion, getting the pros of both solutions (safety+less typing) - although I can say that it's kind of irritating when I get leftover braces after furious edits, screwing the formatting for whole code...

Answer (score 10):

You've cheated indeed. It is more in a spirit of the question to make a function calculating  total cost:

```
double total_cost(double balance);
```

At least you'd be able to reuse it for total costs of years to come.